# LINQ adding new item (student) to a list of another type (courses) using a connector class

Tags: c#, linq, frameworks, entity, dbcontext

Here is my scenario:

**I have:**
[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYsDa.jpg)

**My goal:** 
to add a new student to the list of classes.

**My Code:**

```
    public void addStudent()
    {
        using (RegistarDbContext db = new RegistarDbContext())
        {
            var query = db.tblCourses
                .SelectMany(s => s.tblStudents)
                .ToList();



            query.Add(selectedStudentList);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

**Code Context:** 
selectedStudentList = type of (tblStudent) that's selected from a drop down list

**Other info:** 
Stepping through the program it seems like my student gets added to the variable query, but fails to Save Changes.

Comment: You need to change to `db.Add(selectedStudentList);` because you are adding data to db. The query you need to used for querying and retrieving data from db.

Comment: okay, even when I remove "var query = ", then change query.add to db.add.
It has a compiling error that mentions that there isn't an add function.

I tried even applying .add instead of .ToList but still no results!

I got it to compile like this but it still doesn't save the changes!
`code`db.tblCourses
                    .SelectMany(s => s.tblStudents)
                    .ToList()
                    .Add(selectedStudentList);

                db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Add the namespace `System.Linq`

Comment: System.Linq was included from the begging of the project.

Comment: Don't remove the `var query` instead make a foreach loop with the `.add` and `SaveChanges` and remove the `ToList`

Comment: I've gotten it down to look like something like that `using (RegistarDbContext db = new RegistarDbContext())
            {
                var query = db.tblCourses
                .Select(s => s.tblStudents);

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    item.Add(selectedStudentList);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }` This does add the student to item, but still doesn't save changes!! I've also tried to place the SaveChanges inside the forloop and many other ways of selecting tblstudents but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else would like to know the answer to my question:

```
        public void addStudent()
        {
        //Get the course ID thats been selected.
        var selectedCourseID = selectedCourseList.courseID;

        using (RegistarDbContext db = new RegistarDbContext())
        {
            //Find the course in the database.
            var course = db.tblCourses.Where(c => c.courseID == selectedCourseID).FirstOrDefault();

            //Find the student to add from the database.
            var student = db.tblStudents.Where(s => s.studentID == selectedStudentList.studentID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (checkIfExists(course, student))
                MessageBox.Show("The student is already in the list!", "ERROR: ", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            else
            {
                //Add it to the coruses student list.
                course.tblStudents.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} was successfully enrolled in {1}!", student.fullName, course.name), "Student successfully added!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }
    }
```

**What I've learnt:** 
When adding a student into a course that has a list of student, you must select both the course and the student threw your database.
Only then can you apply the .add function to save the changes in your database!

I hope this saves someone the amount of hours I spent figuring it out :)